# Adding Google Maps to a website

Tags: jquery, html, json, maps

I'm looking to add Google Maps to my dictionary web application. For example, when somebody searches for a country on the dictionary, it shows a Google Map for that country specifically.

HTML Currently:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="author" content="Matthew Hughes">
<title>Dictionary Web Application</title>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="dictionary.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>
 <div id="container">
    <div id="top">
        <header>
             <h1>Dictionary Application</h1>

        </header>
    </div>
    <div id="app">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a word..." id="term" />
        <button id="search">Define!</button>
        <section id="definition"></section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>Created by Matthew Hughes & Spencer Haizel</p>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

jQuery Currently:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#term').focus(function(){
var full = $("#definition").has("definition").length ? true : false;
if(full === false){
 $('#definition').empty();
}
});

var getDefinition = function(){

 var random = $('#term').val();

  if(random === ''){

    $('#definition').html("<h2 class='loading'>We haven't forgotten to validate the form! Please enter a word.</h2>");

 } 

 else {

    $('#definition').html("<h2 class='loading'>Your definition is on its way!</h2>");

    $.getJSON("http://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?from=eng&dest=eng&format=json&phrase=" +random+ "&pretty=true&callback=?", function(json) {

       if (json !== "No definition has been found."){

           var meanings = "";
            json["tuc"].forEach(function(tuc) {
                tuc["meanings"].forEach(function(m) {
                    meanings += "<p>"+m["text"]+"</p>\n";

                });
            });

             $("#definition").html(meanings);



          } 

   else {
             $.getJSON("http://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?from=eng&dest=rus&format=json&phrase=" + "&pretty=true?callback=?", function(json) {
                console.log(json);
                $('#definition').html('<h2 class="loading">Nothing found.</h2><img id="thedefinition" src=' + json.definition[0].image.url + ' />');
             });
          }
     });

  }

return false;
};

$('#search').click(getDefinition);
$('#term').keyup(function(event){
if(event.keyCode === 13){
   getDefinition();
}
});

});
```

The web application currently works for returning definitions for words, but I'm looking to return Google Maps for countries.

Thanks.

Comment: There could be api information on this, but I know I've used a very simply approach for something similar to this: appending it to the google maps url like this: `www.google.com/maps/place/[name of country]`. I'm not entirely sure this would work for your application but figured wouldn't hurt to share. [example](http://www.google.com/maps/place/Pakistan) try clicking that to see.

Comment: You may need to use the search API to return the lat long coordinates, then pass those to the map API. https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

Comment: But the lat/long coordinates are not in the dictionary API I am using.

Comment: Did you sort this? I just tried your link and it seems to be operational, just curious about the outcome.

Comment: Hey @ride_85027 I did indeed get it working, you can see it here: http://spenncerr.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with simple Html. Google maps supports location embedding. To do this, go to the preferred location on Google maps.

[image]

Once you click on the "Share and embed map" switch to the tab that says "Embed map" and copy the embed code. Once copied paste it in your Html page where you want it to appear.

Comment: This will just put a Google map of my prefered location onto the website. I need it to work so that when the user searches for a country through the dictionary, a Google map of that country is shown. You can see the dictionary working here: http://spenncerr.github.io/